# How to count repeated text in excel

Tags: excel, count

I have somewhat an easy question. I'm wondering if there's anyone out there who knows an easy way of counting reoccurring text in excel. Let's say that I have a column where i have counted if kids prefer apples or bananas and there's 200 kids asked in the survey. How do I make excel count all the answers and sum them up. That is, how do I make excel count all the kids that preferred apples and all the kids that preferred bananas without doing it manually? Is there any type of formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a pivot table.

Comment: Use **COUNTIF()** ......................................

Comment: Oh, I used an older version of excel and didn't get Countif to work. Now it's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Image shows using countif and formula as well as a pivot table results.

[image]